# CarrierWave - Set width and max height of images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

I use CarrierWave and I want to resize the images to a width of 220px and a max-height of 220px.
If I use `process :resize_to_fit => [220,220]` it could be that the width is not 220px. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An improvment of Andy H's answer:

```
process :resize => [220, 220]

protected

def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.combine_options do |cmd|
      cmd.resize "#{width}"
      if img[:width] < img[:height]
        cmd.gravity gravity
        cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
        cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
      end
    end
    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If I interpret the question correctly:

- for a portrait image (say 480px wide, 640px high) you would want to scale it down to 220px wide, then crop it down to 220px high, resulting in a square image.
- for a landscape image, you would want to scale it down to 220px wide (the height would therefore be less than 220px).

If that's right, you want a two-step process:

1. Resize to 220px wide, preserving the aspect ratio
2. Crop to 220px high (if portrait)

You can do so by writing your own processor using the `manipulate!` command (see [CarrierWave's own](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb) for some inspiration).

I think this is roughly what you're after

```
process :resize => [220, 220]

protected

def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.combine_options do |cmd|
      cmd.resize width.to_s
      if img[:width] < img[:height]
        cmd.gravity gravity
        cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
        cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
      end
    end
    img = yield(img) if block_given?
    img
  end
end
```

Comment: It says `can't convert Fixnum into String` in the line `cmd.resize width`.

Comment: Ah. Then change it to `"#{width}"` or `width.to_s`.

Comment: But then it says `undefined method 'write' for "":String`

Comment: Ok, I think it was because I forgot to return image from the block.